# GCC-11 installation error in centos 7 (environmental changes)?

Tags: linux, gcc, datascience-anaconda

I installed the latest version of GCC 11.2V using conda, *conda install -c conda-forge* gcc"   in my linux server (Centos7).
After I try to login into my server, after login it shows some weird stuff (look below text).

I'm unable to transfer files between the server and the local computer using scp command.

I couldn't understand what was wrong. How do I solve this error?
If I delete anaconda packages, will the issue be solved ?

Suggestions please.

```
 INFO: activate-binutils_linux-64.sh made the following environmental
 changes:
 +ADDR2LINE=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-addr2line
 +AR=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-ar
 +AS=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-as
 +CXXFILT=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++filt
 +ELFEDIT=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-elfedit
 +GPROF=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gprof
 +HOST=x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu
 +LD_GOLD=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-ld.gold
 +LD=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-ld
 +NM=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-nm
 +OBJCOPY=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-objcopy
 +OBJDUMP=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-objdump
 +RANLIB=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-ranlib
 +READELF=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-readelf
 +SIZE=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-size
 +STRINGS=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-strings
 +STRIP=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-strip *ERROR*: This cross-compiler package contains no program
 /home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc *ERROR:*
 activate-gcc_linux-64.sh failed, see above for details *ERROR:* This
 cross-compiler package contains no program
 /home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc *ERROR:*
 deactivate-gcc_linux-64.sh failed, see above for details INFO:
 deactivate-binutils_linux-64.sh made the following environmental
 changes:
 -ADDR2LINE=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-addr2line
 -AR=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-ar
 -AS=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-as
 -CXXFILT=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++filt
 -ELFEDIT=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-elfedit
 -GPROF=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gprof
 -HOST=x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu
 -LD_GOLD=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-ld.gold
 -LD=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-ld
 -NM=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-nm
 -OBJCOPY=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-objcopy
 -OBJDUMP=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-objdump
 -RANLIB=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-ranlib
 -READELF=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-readelf
 -SIZE=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-size
 -STRINGS=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-strings
 -STRIP=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-strip INFO: activate-binutils_linux-64.sh made the following environmental
 changes:
 +ADDR2LINE=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-addr2line
 +AR=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-ar
 +AS=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-as
 +CXXFILT=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-c++filt
 +ELFEDIT=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-elfedit
 +GPROF=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-gprof
 +HOST=x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu
 +LD_GOLD=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-ld.gold
 +LD=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-ld
 +NM=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-nm
 +OBJCOPY=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-objcopy
 +OBJDUMP=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-objdump
 +RANLIB=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-ranlib
 +READELF=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-readelf
 +SIZE=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-size
 +STRINGS=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-strings
 +STRIP=/home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-strip *ERROR:* This cross-compiler package contains no program
 /home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc *ERROR:*
 activate-gcc_linux-64.sh failed, see above for details
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's a bit too late. But I was having similar issues..
That might be a bug.

I could solve it this ways:
remove `gcc` (and `gxx` if you have it in your current env)

```
conda remove gcc
```

then install

```
conda install -c anaconda gcc_linux-64 gxx_linux-64
```

or

```
conda install -c conda-forge mamba
mamba install -c anaconda gcc_linux-64 gxx_linux-64
```

I would highly recommend `mamba` since it's super fast!

For things like:

```
*ERROR:* This cross-compiler package contains no program
 /home/sun/anaconda3/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc
```

I did the following (dirty solution):
check the path of the missing file in your env eg `my_env`

```
which x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc
```

..in my case that gave: `./miniconda3/envs/my_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc`

Now copy that file in to `./miniconda3/bin/`

```
scp ./miniconda3/envs/my_env/bin/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc ./miniconda3/bin/

conda deactivate
conda activate my_env
```

no more errors or warnings, hope this helps.

Comment: Why would you use ``scp`` for a local file copy?